# Python: Having "not-yet-defined" class-names as default-arguments

Tags: python, class, parameters, arguments, default-parameters

I have a "class1" which must be able to create an object of a
different class-name. The class-name is passed as an argument called "friend".
I want the "friend"-argument to default to a class-name called "class2".

Additionally I need to have the same behavior for the class "class2".
So "class2" should have "class1" as a default friend-argument:

```
class class1():
 def __init__(self, friend = class2):
  self.friendInstance = friend()

class class2():
 def __init__(self, friend = class1):
  self.friendInstance = friend()

class1()
class2()
```

Now i get the following error-message:

```
    def __init__(self, friend = class2):
NameError: name 'class2' is not defined
```

Of course, i can't define class2 before class1 because
this would result in a similar error: "class1" is not defined.
Do you know a solution?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Henry

Comment: That would be an endless recursion if it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can push it to later:

```
class class1(object):
    def __init__(self, friend=None):
        if friend is None:
            friend = class2
        self.friendInstance = friend()
```

**Edit:** Actually, don't do that. It will create a class2 instance that creates a class1 instance that creates a class2 instance, etc. Maybe you really want to pass an instance in instead of the class to be instantiated:

```
class class1(object):
    def __init__(self, friend=None):
        if friend is None:
            self.friendInstance = class2(self)
        else:
            self.friendInstance = friend
```

and likewise for class2. That isn't as flexible, but it's pretty simple. If you really want flexibility, you can do something like this:

```
class class1(object):
    def __init__(self, friend=None, friendClass=None):
        if friend is None:
            self.friendInstance = (class2 if friendClass is None else friendClass)(self)
        else:
            self.friendInstance = friend

class class2(object):
    def __init__(self, friend=None, friendClass=class1):
        if friend is None:
            self.friendInstance = friendClass(self)
        else:
            self.friendInstance = friend
```

That could be simplified with inheritance or metaclasses, but you probably get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you solve the `NameError`, you'll run into another -- namely that you've attempting to create a recursive data-structure. Each instance of `class1` attempts to *create* an instance of `class2`, which likewise attempts to *create* another `class1` instance, etc, etc, ad infinitum (actually only until you get a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`).

Without knowing a little more about what you're actually trying to do, here's one simple solution:

```
class class1(object):
    def __init__(self, friend=None):
        if friend is None:
            friend = class2(self) # create a class2 instance with myself as a friend
        self.friendInstance = friend

class class2(object):
    def __init__(self, friend=None):
        if friend is None:
            friend = class1(self) # create a class1 instance with myself as a friend
        self.friendInstance = friend

print class1()
# <__main__.class1 object at 0x00B42450>
print class2()
# <__main__.class2 object at 0x00B65530>
```